# Sharing digital data on physical medium

Tags: written-material, information

**How can one store digital data in a manner readable without a computer?**

To pose a more concrete frame around the question, let's assume we can transport some limited amount of mass into the 1950s and want to convey as much information as possible.

(An alternative may be to create a time capsule in the expectation of humanity's decay, but as of now I am not asking for a good *archival* solution or self-bootstrapping information presentation.)

I saw a similar question elsewhere and will post my ideas as an answer below. However, I am interested in more futuristic (+20 years from now) options and further ideas I did not stumble upon.

Comment: Why specifically digital data? Digital implies encoded, so why is it necessary to preserve this, or is it? Why not send a book - low tech, practical and reasonably resilient to being mishandled?

Comment: I'm adding the \[written-material\] tag because, even though you are asking about *digital* data (and see Lee Leon's comment above), you are asking about ways that do not require a computer for reading the data. So while \[written-material\] is mainly about paper and similar material, it seems applicable here. Feel free to roll back or to edit further if you disagree.

Comment: I think it got carried over from the mentioned question somewhere. Also, all our data is more or less digital now (or can be digitalised). As for a book – yes, that's an option. But sending in a single micro-SD card will provide more information than a library _and_ it will help with weight budget. The only question is how to read it with relatively "low-tech" or what alternatives are, which is sort of my premise.

Comment: Technically all data can be read without a computer if you have the right equipment. The computer just makes it much easier to read lots of it.

Comment: Well, yes, you could read a CD with a microscope, optionally a camera, and a bunch of human computers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_computer). But to go such length you'd need a hint of the value of the data on that CD. Or the sender could just have sent a PC with that CD. Or even instead of it.

Comment: Anything you choose will require equipment and technology to read. If you send back a 1GB file on w/e you choose, if you don't have a way to decode for the people, they can't do a thing. The problem here isn't the information or the fact that it is digital, the problem is humans can't read densely pack information in any form. The one of the easiest thing you can do would be send back a book and print the text really small. If you encode the data at all, people manually doing decoding on data will be a very slow process without modern computers no matter what the format.

Comment: Simply trying to decode a billion words through simple modern text compression manually might take longer than developing the technology to do it digitally. You'd run into the same problems with pretty much all artificially packed data.

Comment: Are you sending data backward in time from today, backward in time from 20 years into the future, or forward in time?  It's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had two use cases. Backward in time from 20 years in the future and time capsule.

Comment: From your comments, are you suggesting that you are looking to send back a small enough amount of data that it's not *worth* using a computer to process it?  How much data are we talking about?

Comment: I was just curious and not that I have some fix physical constraints. But I was looking into high information content / physical volume ratio, but without a need to develop a new Manhattan project to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to sending massive amounts of information, forget calling it data we're just too digitally obsessed to see the wood for the trees, into the 1950s was, of course, solved in the 1940s by the American engineer Vannevar Bush.

He proposed etching information onto advanced versions of microfilm. This was called Memex. A place marker name for his hypothetical encyclopedia and library system of the future. However, this concept was later extended to using metallic wafers. The characters so inscribed were intended by to be read by an electron microscope.

> Today Bush is also remembered as a prophet in another field, computer science. In a 1945 article entitled “As We May Think,” published in the Atlantic Monthly, Bush proposed a device that he called the Memex—an indexed, archival, microfilm machine for cross-referencing and retrieving information. For Bush, this article was an extension of his work in analog computing and microfilm technology. To the modern reader it portends the creation of hypertext and the World Wide Web.

Source: [Vannevar Bush biography](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Vannevar-Bush)

[Memex](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1945/07/as-we-may-think/303881/) would be a concept and a technology readily understandable and implementable by technical people in the 1950s and therefore it would be an excellent medium for sending information into the 1950s.

The original proposal for storing high-density information for retrieval via electron microscopy was not able to be located. However, this [more recent proposal](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.89248) for a such a device was: --

> A concept for a high‐density memory‐storage device is described. Information is recorded as small implanted p+ (or n+) diodes, formed by a focused ion beam, on the n+ (or p+) surface of a large‐area diode and read by a focused electron beam. Preliminary experimental results using ion implantation through an aperture mask to simulate a focused ion beam, and a scanning electron microscope for readout, demonstrate better than 0.5‐μ bit spacing. Evaluation indicates that 10^10 bits/cm^2 storage density is possible, with ≳10 Mbits/sec write/read rates, and access times <30 μsec to 10^11‐bit data fields.

Source:

> Published Online: August 2008
>
> Information‐storage device using surface diodes
>
> Appl. Phys. Lett. 30, 592 (1977); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.89248
>
> C. G. Kirkpatrick, G. E. Possin, and J. F. Norton

Essentially electron microscope Memex information stored on metal wafers will do the trick. Of course, an instruction manual wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 3):

### Micro Etching in metal

http://rosettaproject.org/ have decided that for long term storage of data the best way is to micro etch in onto a metal disk whoch is then coated for protection. It only requires a 650X microscope to read.

The data could be encoded to be read by a computer scanner (I am a little confused as to why you read digital data without a computer it seems a little ackward but I think I know what you mean)

Comment: This also has an added benefit in that, if you know the capabilities of the time and geographical period you're going to (as in this case), or if you need a gradually higher-density storage format, you can adjust the required magnification accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**Painting**

This problem has been solved long time ago, when the necessity to convey messages to a vast number of people not able to read it was urgent.

[image: Sistine chapel fresco]

With just few square meters of painting you can illustrate the entire Universal Judgement (in the case of the Sistine Chapel) without the need to be teach the viewers how to read the Bible.

Comment: And it's aesthetically pleasing too.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what amount of information one wants to store and what machinery does the other side have. Let's look at the whole spectrum.

- QR codes and such are productively used to store computer-readable information on a physical medium. They a limited to a quite small data amount and are tedious to read without a computer.
- [Microfiches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microform) can store quite a lot of information, are normally readable with a special device, but a reader can be improvised. With a bit of thought the most essential information can be read with a naked eye or with a hand lens. Microfishes can be also archived for a longer time.
- If the other side has or can be provided a fitting computer (time capsule!), why not using a usual computer medium?

  - Things like handful of SD cards can carry a lot, but what about survival of information in harsh environment? One would need some kind of data duplication in any case.
  - A staple of hard drives might also be not a good idea, they have moving part that may decay.
  - What about decay of the computer needed to drive all these parts?
  - If decay not a problem (message into the past), why just not send a computer as such? Deciding on the recipient and teaching them to interact with the machine might be a larger problem...
- If human readability is a nice bonus and might even inevitably range to required, why not just *print* all the data? In the "back to the past" scenario one does not even need to care about good machine readability.

  - If printing does not convey enough information per gram of mass, [shorthand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand) or stenotype might help. This would need an instruction on how to read this, but it would be typically needed anyway.
  - It seems that all non-computer-readable media confine us to static information. (A video is also static in a sense, it can't change live, on the fly.)

Actually, multi-layer schemes are tempting, especially if the development level of the recipient is not really known (time capsule or possible recipient mishap). First bunch of instructions are cartoonish with some guide on the language and further reading. Next: written text with guide to shorthand writing. Next: how to build a microphishe viewer. On the phishes: the SD card pinout, interface, and the layout of a primitive file system. On the cards: building plans for a somewhat advanced computer and for a 3D printer with the precision needed to build a reader for holographic just-few-atoms-per-bit super-futuristic hoola-hoola (remember, future?) with the *actual* payload. It should be interesting, but less so than other preceding things. Or it should just take up so much volume that it is plainly impossible to convey otherwise. In any case, one would possibly not need to convey *more* information than that in such special circumstances.

Comment: Why have you answered your own question? - Ah, I see, you explained that in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @LeeLeon Posting a self-answer is perfectly permissible and even encouraged. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the [help]. There's even a checkbox in the [ask question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) form specifically for simultaneously posting a question and an answer. Obviously, the question must still be on topic, and the answer should *ideally* be judged no differently than if some other user had posted it (in practice, my experience is that self-answers tend to be judged a bit more harshly).

Answer (score 0):

In the DNA. This is not by any means my idea: see [Science](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/355/6328/950.full), [Wired](https://www.wired.com/2017/03/quantum-computers-used-hard-drives-made-dna/). The DNA is organic database. Now, sending this back in time is perfect because your message is capable of self-replicating.

Now, what about reading, you may ask. Veering away from plausible science, we could imagine that your DNA message also contains a "reader software" in the form of some genes that make the stored information readable by low tech. The DNA may be in the seed of a tree that starts growing leaves with text on them. The message could be a virus that makes the infected person speak the message out loud (Tourette syndrome).

Comment: Why involve biology at all? Rather than sending back a seed which will grow into a tree and print out a message you could just send a book instead. DNA has advantage of being information-dense, but you lose that advantage if you can only "read" the contents through macroscopic phenotypes.

Comment: That's _very_ original. Definitely did not regard that, thanks. Unsure if it's really doable on the larger scale in a +20 years setting.

Comment: Biology because there was restriction on the amount of matter that can be sent.

Comment: @OlegLobachev As a storeage technology (with a computer assisted reader) This technology is being developed to get around our current data crunch. here is another reference http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/03/dna-could-store-all-worlds-data-one-room . 
The reading without a computer is a problem. but what if all the DNA coded for was to produce an uneven surface that could be read in a microscope?

Comment: One could also consider the reason of sending the message back (or forward) in time. Disseminating useful information obviously serves as means to further the science and improve human condition. To serve this goal, the ideal message is a DNA-modifying virus that 1. reduces violence and 2. improves IQ of the species. Given that, they will not kill each other and figure the rest out without help from future.

Comment: @Congenital Optimist Very interesting, but the way the discussion evolves, it answers a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Ultra high density storage has had demonstrators in the past.

The one I am referring to uses quartz disks that is purported to be able to hold around 360TB for "billions of years"

> Scientists believe they have built a quartz coin that can store 360 TB of data for billions of years, presenting the opportunity for the entire humankind history to be recorded and preserved likely well after humans are extinct.

> These quartz coins were produced at the University of Southampton, which built on technology from Hitachi in conjunction with Kyoto University. The femtosecond laser used to inscribe terabytes of data provides unique ways to protect and preserve data that is otherwise unheard of in modern day data storage.

> How Does 5D Data Storage Work In Quartz?

> The 5D data storage uses a femtosecond laser (10−15), a similar type of laser used for Lasik eye surgery, to encode information in 5 dimensions. The first three dimensions are X, Y, and Z to denote the nano-grating's location in space within the quartz coin. The 4th and 5th dimension are two additional forms of information on the birefringence patterns of the nano-gratings. The 4th dimension is the slow axis orientation while the strength of retardance is the 5th dimension. The fourth and fifth dimension relate to how light travels into the quartz, hits the nano-grating, and how the light responds after hitting the nano-grating. In a very simplistic sense, think of a prism that takes in white light and emits a rainbow. Scientists can control the slow axis orientation and the retardance by polarization and intensity of the light beam.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/trevornace/2016/03/20/quartz-coin-hold-360-tb-data-billions-years/?sh=1214b1136662

Company site: https://www.5dmemorycrystal.com/

For further reading, "quartz storage disk" is usually the best search term.

Note that this requires very specialized equipment to write to and read from.

Answer (score 0):

**Holography**

Holographic storage is incredibly dense and has the advantage that it can be read by human eye directly just by shining monochromatic coherent light on the storage medium. The medium can be a very thin foil. It was actually invented in the 1940s. They had plenty of monochromatic lights in 1950 (gas discharge tubes) and coherency too can be achieved with litle technical difficulty (make light soure as point-like as possible).